# How do native Android 4.0 apps have very fast scrolling ListViews?

Tags: android, performance, listview

I am comparing performances, specifically scrolling speeds of a `ListView`, of apps that I create, to native Android 4.0 apps - Gmail, Gtalk, etc.

One thing I have noticed is that the scrolling frame rate of a `ListView` on the native Android apps are very high - almost 60fps. In my apps, a `ListView` don't scroll nearly as fast.

Assuming I'm using `ListView` incorrectly (which I'm not - I've followed everything stated here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70), I decided to create a dummy `ListView` that just returns a dozen almost empty `LinearLayout` views as it's rows (yes I'm using convertView correctly). What's disturbing here is that my almost blank `ListView` has slower scrolling performance than any of the native apps - Gmail, Gtalk, Contacts, etc.

As a side note, a simple `ScrollView` has really good scrolling performance, but it is inadvisable to use a `ScrollView` for large lists.

Clearly, the native apps are doing something (or have access to something) that I don't understand. Unfortunately these native apps aren't open source. Does anyone have any insight as to how these native apps achieve such tremendous performance?

Answer (score 1):

After look at the source code for the native email application, I have found that the list items in a list of messages are single Views, not ViewGroups like LinearLayout. That makes for a very flat View hierarchy which leads to a better frame rate while scrolling the list. I think I remember watching a video of a talk by Romain Guy (one of the lead Android UI engineers) that mentioned that the Gmail team did something similar to increase performance.
To achieve this yourself, you'd have to subclass View and draw everything in the View yourself in the onDraw() method.

[Here](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_email/blob/master/src/com/android/email/activity/MessageListItem.java) is the source for a message list item in the current email application.

They do a cool trick where you inflate a view (but don't attach it), get the coordinates of where the items go based on the ViewGroup it is in, and cache the coordinates in a Map so when a view is recycled in a list you don't have to inflate that view again. I might try this in a future project of mine!

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

There are some techniques to make `ListView` faster: caching and using dissapeared list items as new list items to avoid long operation of creating them. You need to create your own class based on `ListView` to realize these techniques. Read more [here](http://www.google.kz/search?q=listview%20android%20convert&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aru%3aofficial&client=firefox#sclient=psy-ab&hl=ru&client=firefox&hs=KI8&rls=org.mozilla%3aru%3aofficial&source=hp&q=fast%20listview%20android%20convertview&pbx=1&oq=fast%20listview%20android%20convertview&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=272658l273283l1l273513l5l4l0l0l0l1l694l694l5-1l1l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=14e30fe4777d0e3c&biw=1680&bih=933).

Comment: Caching views is definitely not recommended according to this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70

Answer (score 0):

I also followed on that video to build my list view. In my app, there are not much items (rows). But I think if we just do as the video said, we are on right way, at least on the theory?

Comment: I agree that theoretically as long as we follow the video, we are on the right track. But comparing results with native apps proves otherwise.